# SVG in iOS, wrong parsing

Tags: ios, svg, парсер

Сегодня дизайнер прислал мне архив с svg, я добавил их в приложение и получил следующую картину (например, потому что подобное повторяется со всеми свг)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при том, что саму svg всё, в том числе и xcode и adobe illustrator и превью на macos показывает следующим образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код свг при этом выглядит так

```
<svg id="iMap-all" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 366.4 512">
<path d="M183.2,0C82.2,0,0,82.2,0,183.2,0,278,137.1,380.7,176.8,507.4a6.67,6.67,0,0,0,6.3,4.6,6.42,6.42,0,0,0,6.2-4.7c38.5-129.8,177.1-229.2,177.1-324.1C366.4,82.2,284.2,0,183.2,0Zm0,322.2c-79.2,0-143.7-64.5-143.7-143.7S103.9,34.8,183.2,34.8,326.8,99.2,326.8,178.5,262.4,322.2,183.2,322.2Z" fill="#c3181d"/>
<circle cx="183.2" cy="178.5" r="143.7" fill="#fff"/><path d="M119.1,168.3a20.27,20.27,0,0,0,13.9,5.6,19.85,19.85,0,0,0,12.8-4.6V129.8H91.4a6.27,6.27,0,0,0-6.3,6.3v17.7a20.1,20.1,0,0,0,20.1,20.1A20.74,20.74,0,0,0,119.1,168.3Z" fill="#2b2b2b"/>
<path d="M145.8,179.3a20.08,20.08,0,0,1-26.7-1,20.27,20.27,0,0,1-13.9,5.6,19.71,19.71,0,0,1-9.7-2.5V258a6.27,6.27,0,0,0,6.3,6.3h44Zm-13.9,44.8H111.8a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.3-6.3V197.7a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3-6.3h20.1a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3,6.3v20.1A6.27,6.27,0,0,1,131.9,224.1Z" fill="#2b2b2b"/><path d="M267.3,88.7h-109v50.2a20.08,20.08,0,0,0,25.8-1.7,20.27,20.27,0,0,0,13.9,5.6,19.83,19.83,0,0,0,13.9-5.6,20.27,20.27,0,0,0,13.9,5.6,19.83,19.83,0,0,0,13.9-5.6,20.27,20.27,0,0,0,13.9,5.6h0a20.1,20.1,0,0,0,20.1-20.1V95A6.56,6.56,0,0,0,267.3,88.7Z" fill="#2b2b2b"/>
<path d="M190.5,264.3V217.8a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3-6.3H227a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3,6.3v46.5h28.9a6.27,6.27,0,0,0,6.3-6.3V146.3a20,20,0,0,1-14.9,6.7h0a19.83,19.83,0,0,1-13.9-5.6,20.27,20.27,0,0,1-13.9,5.6,19.83,19.83,0,0,1-13.9-5.6A20.27,20.27,0,0,1,198,153a19.83,19.83,0,0,1-13.9-5.6,20.08,20.08,0,0,1-25.8,1.7V264.4h32.2Zm18.1-76.6a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.3,6.3H182.2a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.3-6.3V167.6a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3-6.3h20.1a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3,6.3Zm40.2,0a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.3,6.3H222.4a6.27,6.27,0,0,1-6.3-6.3V167.6a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3-6.3h20.1a6.27,6.27,0,0,1,6.3,6.3v20.1Z" fill="#2b2b2b"/></svg>
```

То есть за исключением кривого viewbox ничего собенного. Я как человек, в свг и дизайне понимающий мало, поступаю достаточно бессовестно, я открываю эту svg в adobe illustrator и сохраняю ее со стандартными настройками, в результате ее код изменяется

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="iMap-all" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 366.3999939 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 366.3999939 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#C3181D;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st2{fill:#2B2B2B;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M183.1999969,0C82.1999969,0,0,82.1999969,0,183.1999969
    C0,278,137.1000061,380.7000122,176.8000031,507.3999939c0.8910217,2.7294922,3.4288025,4.582489,6.3000031,4.6000061
    c2.8887024,0.0065918,5.4260864-1.9169006,6.1999969-4.7000122c38.5-129.7999878,177.1000214-229.2000122,177.1000214-324.1000061
    C366.3999939,82.1999969,284.2000122,0,183.1999969,0z M183.1999969,322.2000122C104,322.2000122,39.5,257.7000122,39.5,178.5000153
    S103.9000015,34.7999992,183.1999969,34.7999992S326.7999878,99.1999969,326.7999878,178.5
    S262.3999939,322.2000122,183.1999969,322.2000122z"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="183.1999969" cy="178.5" r="143.6999969"/>
<path class="st2" d="M119.0999985,168.3000031c3.7478714,3.5737305,8.7214279,5.5774689,13.9000015,5.6000061
    c4.6752472,0.0219116,9.2082062-1.6071167,12.8000031-4.6000061v-39.5H91.4000015
    c-3.4627838-0.0166168-6.2833939,2.7770691-6.3000031,6.2398529c-0.0000992,0.02005-0.0000992,0.0401001,0,0.0601501v17.6999969
    c0,11.1009216,8.9990692,20.1000061,20.0999908,20.1000061c0.0000076,0,0.0000076,0,0.0000076,0
    C110.3693466,173.8309937,115.3265533,171.833847,119.0999985,168.3000031z"/>
<path class="st2" d="M145.8000031,179.3000031c-7.8625488,6.4954376-19.3453522,6.0653687-26.6999969-1
    c-3.7478714,3.5737305-8.7214279,5.5774689-13.9000015,5.6000061c-3.3946686,0.0158997-6.7359085-0.8452454-9.6999969-2.5V258
    c-0.0166016,3.4627991,2.7770844,6.2833862,6.2398682,6.2999878c0.0200424,0.0000916,0.0400925,0.0000916,0.0601349,0h44.0000076
    L145.8000031,179.3000031z M131.9000092,224.1000061h-20.1000061c-3.4627838,0.0166168-6.2833939-2.7770691-6.3000031-6.2398529
    c-0.0000992-0.02005-0.0000992-0.0401001,0-0.0601501v-20.1000061c-0.0166092-3.4627838,2.7770691-6.2833862,6.2398529-6.3000031
    c0.02005-0.0000916,0.0401001-0.0000916,0.0601501,0h20.1000061c3.4627838-0.0166168,6.2833862,2.7770691,6.3000031,6.2398529
    c0.0000916,0.02005,0.0000916,0.0401001,0,0.0601501v20.1000061c0.0166168,3.4627838-2.7770691,6.2833862-6.2398529,6.3000031
    c-0.02005,0.0000916-0.0401154,0.0000916-0.0601654,0H131.9000092z"/>
<path class="st2" d="M267.2999878,88.6999969h-109v50.1999969c7.8692932,5.782196,18.7574463,5.0647583,25.8000031-1.6999969
    c3.7478638,3.5737305,8.7214203,5.5774689,13.8999939,5.6000061c5.1874542,0.0233002,10.1774902-1.9870758,13.8999939-5.6000061
    c3.7478638,3.5737305,8.7214203,5.5774689,13.8999939,5.6000061c5.1874542,0.0233002,10.1774902-1.9870758,13.8999939-5.6000061
    c3.7478638,3.5737305,8.7214203,5.5774689,13.8999939,5.6000061l0,0c11.1009064,0,20.0999908-8.9990845,20.0999908-20.0999985V95
    C273.5636902,91.5400238,270.7616882,88.7817917,267.2999878,88.6999969z"/>
<path class="st2" d="M190.5,264.2999878v-46.4999847c-0.0166168-3.4627838,2.7770691-6.2833862,6.2398529-6.3000031
    c0.02005-0.0000916,0.0401001-0.0000916,0.0601501,0H227c3.4627838-0.0166168,6.2833862,2.7770691,6.3000031,6.2398529
    c0.0000916,0.02005,0.0000916,0.0401001,0,0.0601501v46.4999847h28.9000092
    c3.4627991,0.0166016,6.2833862-2.7770691,6.2999878-6.2398682c0.0000916-0.02005,0.0000916-0.0400696,0-0.0601196V146.3000031
    c-3.7864685,4.2525177-9.2060242,6.6894989-14.8999939,6.6999969l0,0
    c-5.1874542,0.0233002-10.1774902-1.9870758-13.8999939-5.6000061c-3.7478638,3.5737305-8.7214203,5.5774689-13.8999939,5.6000061
    c-5.1874542,0.0233002-10.1774902-1.9870758-13.8999939-5.6000061C208.1521454,150.9737396,203.1785736,152.977478,198,153
    c-5.1874542,0.0233002-10.1774902-1.9870758-13.8999939-5.6000061c-7.0425568,6.7647552-17.9307098,7.482193-25.8000031,1.6999969
    v115.3000031H190.5V264.2999878z M208.6000061,187.6999817c0.0166168,3.4627838-2.7770691,6.2833862-6.2398529,6.3000031
    c-0.02005,0.0000916-0.0401001,0.0000916-0.0601501,0h-20.1000061c-3.4627838,0.0166168-6.2833862-2.7770691-6.3000031-6.2398529
    c-0.0000916-0.02005-0.0000916-0.0401001,0-0.0601501v-20.0999756c-0.0166168-3.4627838,2.7770691-6.2833862,6.2398529-6.3000031
    c0.02005-0.0000916,0.0401001-0.0000916,0.0601501,0h20.1000061c3.4627838-0.0166168,6.2833862,2.7770691,6.3000031,6.2398529
    c0.0000916,0.02005,0.0000916,0.0401001,0,0.0601501V187.6999817z M248.8000031,187.6999817
    c0.0166168,3.4627838-2.7770691,6.2833862-6.2398529,6.3000031c-0.02005,0.0000916-0.0401001,0.0000916-0.0601501,0h-20.1000061
    c-3.4627838,0.0166168-6.2833862-2.7770691-6.3000031-6.2398529c-0.0000916-0.02005-0.0000916-0.0401001,0-0.0601501v-20.0999756
    c-0.0166168-3.4627838,2.7770691-6.2833862,6.2398529-6.3000031c0.02005-0.0000916,0.0401001-0.0000916,0.0601501,0H242.5
    c3.4627838-0.0166168,6.2833862,2.7770691,6.3000031,6.2398529c0.0000916,0.02005,0.0000916,0.0401001,0,0.0601501v20.1000061
    V187.6999817z"/>
</svg>
```

Запускаю приложение и вижу, что все свг в приложении стали цвета #000, то есть в данном случае "капля" становится полностью черной. Пробовал и JAMSVG и SVGgh и ставший частью SDK SVGKit, но результат один. Ни дизайнер, ни другие, имевшие раньше дело с свг разводят руками, да и самому не понятно, вроде очевидный path парсится криво, а после сохранения еще и чертным

то же самое произошло с одноцветными иконками, после ai они приняли в приложении правильную форму вместо кривой, но закрасились черным цветом. Раньше работал с свг нормально.

Есть мысли по поводу того, чем это может быть вызвано?

Comment: Интересно. На отрисованных SVG исключительно выпуклые фигуры. В математическом смысле.

Comment: Похоже на проблемы с маской, думаю надо разложить на простые `path` без дырок внутри. Я кстати некоторые иконки от дизайнера рисую руками в коде точка за точкой, получается намного чище да и времени отнимет такая иконка максимум час

Answer (score 1):

У меня в inkscape картинка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогает поставить пробелы перед минусами `-`.